# When download app in beta version from google play store appering two apps?

Tags: android, apk, beta

I upload an apk in beta mode, then when app is upload in beta and i download in my device i can see two apps whith ditinct name example badi.badi and badi. i dont understand this behaivor.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean there is two apps one called 'badi.badi' and one 'badi'?

Comment: Yes in same download appering two icons in device "same image ", my app name is badi in  manifest file, and pakage name  is com.badi.badi . Thanks